# Experiment on WebQuestionsSP data set based on freebase

Tags: freebase, knowledge-graph

I'm trying to test the performance of my KBQA system on WebQuestionsSP. Unfortunately, freebase is no longer accessible through the API. But I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how I could conduct this experiment now. Is deploying freebase Data Dump locally the only solution? I would rather have other ways to solve this problem because freebase Data Dump is too big and difficult to deploy.

I have found FB2M and FB5M that seem to be potentially feasible solutions, but there are also blogs saying that the real link situation between entities in FB2M and FB5M is different from the InferentialChain in the WebQSP dataset.